# How can I fire fake uevents on Linux like e.g. power supply getting offline?

Tags: linux, testing, events, linux-kernel, udev

I need my code to get executed when AC power gets on / off. So I would like to receive power supply plug / unplug events for testing purposes. Unit testing is an option, and using a real laptop is an option. But I hoped there is some intermediate way e.g. to make kernel generate a fake event. Executing `echo offline > /sys/class/power_supply/ACAD/uevent` does not work. Is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/493803/64699

Answer (score 0):

shall you try cmd follow
sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=power_supply --action=add